# Float right not working?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

I have tried many solutions on SO and none of them seem to work. I have tried many different methods of getting navbar-right to work but to no avail.

"Login" should be on the right.

Here is my nav:

```
<div class="navbar-header">

  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo.png">
  </a>
</div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-nav">
    <a href="index.php"><li>Coin Flip</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Deposit</li></a>
    <a href="index.php"><li>Support</li></a>
    <a href="index.php"><li>FAQ</li></a>
    <a href="index.php"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
    <a href="index.php"><li><i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
  </ul>
  <div class="right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="index.php"><li>Login</li></a>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

And the relevant css:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #0C1322;
    box-shadow: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 0;
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: inset 1px #2F394E;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 25px;
}


.navbar a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #BDC0C5 !important;
    word-wrap: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    align-self: center;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
}

.navbar a .fa {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #4c7ba3 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.main-nav {
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I have tried multiple positions, displays, etc. I think the issue might be in the flex box? When I added a container around the uls, it pulled right but also broke my flex box centering.

Thanks!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ga3rcg0w/ (Make sure to expand the web view)

Comment: Please post jsfiddle or working demo as by given code we are not able to get minimum working example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Using Inspect Element on your browser.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="float:right">
     <a href="index.php"><li>Login</li></a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I plan to make it responsive after I get this working.

Comment: I think so problem in "display:flex" in .navbar class.try remove display:flex from .navbar class.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to make the `.navbar` position to relative, and some change and add code for `right` class.

And the code looks :

```
    .navbar {
        background-color: #0C1322;
        box-shadow: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        border: 0;
        height: 70px;
        border-bottom: inset 1px #2F394E;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 25px;
        position:relative;               /* <-- Add This */
    }


    /* New Style */


    .right {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
    }

    .right ul {
      margin-right:10px;
    }
```

It should work like what you expected :)

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer - also i hope you arnt building a csgo betting website with no knowledge  of css/html yet alone api and more.

Comment: Check out one of my previous site www.csgosweep.com

Comment: Still not budging the ul/div.
Could it be a flexbox quirk?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with this.

```
.right {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Float does not work due to the flex box.